# Randomly getting errors on Wagmi useWaitForTransaction and useContractWrite hooks

Tags: ethers.js, react, wagmi

I'm using a **Wagmi** library in my **ReactJS** application and one specific hook(s) are randomly throwing errors.

Sometimes it's not an error and the task executes fine, or it's throwing one of 2 errors randomly.

---

Code Snippet:

```js
  const {
    write: approveToken0,
    data: approveToken0Data,
    isError: onApproveToken0Error,
  } = useContractWrite({
    address: token0Address as `0x${string}`,
    abi: ERC20_ABI,
    functionName: "approve",
  });
  const approveToken0Tx = useWaitForTransaction({ hash: approveToken0Data?.hash });
```

Calling the hook:

```js
approveToken0({ args: [SWAPEX_ADDRESS, ethers.parseUnits(amount)] });
```

Error 1:
[image]

Transaction from Error 1: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x81a4604faec0666d0b48b121fe56015a6a44332c721659c0cbbb99e8ad47edb2

Error2: [image]

Transaction from Error 2: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xfc8e30839742cb6f4fb5f3b41df2b45c849ee29481e65310fbabffa1bffbbc4e

---

I had zero problems when I was working with the local hardhat blockchain. The current network is Goerli where the problem occurs.

I tried adding `chainId` or `confirmations` options to hooks but no results.

I was researching this problem but found literally nothing. I hope someone can help here and maybe this question can also help others experiencing the same problem.

Versions:

```
    "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit": "^1.0.1",
    "ethers": "^6.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "wagmi": "^1.0.9"
```

Comment: I've also tried using `writeContract` and `waitForTransaction` from `wagmi/actions` but still, once in a while I get BlockNotFoundError..

Comment: Nika, did you figure that out?

Comment: I've figured it out. It's because of the public provider nodes. Connecting to nodes with the API key solves this issue. Here's the discussion: https://github.com/wagmi-dev/wagmi/issues/2530

Comment: Thanks Nika! I figured that issue after looking at your discussion on GitHub. Yes, public nodes sometimes throw these errors.